# search feature php and mysql view result in current page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to create a search feature in php which get the value of an input and search it in a db. 
I have this code:

```
<center><form method="post" id="search" action="search.php?go">

        <p>

            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />

            <input type="submit" id="search_btn" name="submit" value="Cerca utente" />
        </p>

    </form></center>
```

and in a php file I have create this:

```
public function searchUser($nomeUtente)
    {

        $sql = "SELECT uUsername FROM users WHERE='$nomeUtente' ";

        if( !$this->stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql) )
            throw new Exception("MySQL Prepare statement failed: ".$this->mysqli->error);

        $this->stmt->execute();
        $this->stmt->store_result();
        $this->stmt->bind_result($nome);
        if( $this->stmt->num_rows == 0)
            return "Nessun nome corrispondente.";
        $nomi = array();
        $i = 0;
        while( $this->stmt->fetch() ){
        $nomi[$i]["nome"] = $nome;
           }


        return $nomi;

    }
```

How I can view the result of my query in a table on the current page? I don't want to view result in another page but in the page where the search form is.

Comment: For that you have to use call php function using Ajax jquery. Than you can replace your result div in current page div without refresh your current page.

Answer (score 0):

```
***HTML***

    <center><form method="post" id="search" action="search.php?go">

            <p>

                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />

                <input type="submit" id="search_btn" name="submit" value="Cerca utente" />
            </p>

        </form></center>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#search_btn').click(function(){

    var Name=$('#name').val();
    $.Post('Search.php',{Name:Name},function(data)
{
alert(data);
});

    });


    });
    </script>
```

***PHP (must be saved as search.php)***

```
<?php
if($_isset($_POST["Name"]))
{
$Name=$_POST["Name"];


searchUser($Name);

public function searchUser($nomeUtente)
    {

        $sql = "SELECT uUsername FROM users WHERE='$nomeUtente' ";

        if( !$this->stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql) )
            throw new Exception("MySQL Prepare statement failed: ".$this->mysqli->error);

        $this->stmt->execute();
        $this->stmt->store_result();
        $this->stmt->bind_result($nome);
        if( $this->stmt->num_rows == 0)
            return "Nessun nome corrispondente.";
        $nomi = array();
        $i = 0;
        while( $this->stmt->fetch() ){
        $nomi[$i]["nome"] = $nome;
           }


        return $nomi;

    }

}

?>
```